# RegEx Python - I Want to write RegEx by which I can replace { expression } into {% print expression %}

Tags: python, regex

I am want to write a RegEx in Python which will change string if `{{ expression }}` occurs in the string, into `{% print expression %}` like

```
{{ a+b }} 

to 

{% print a+b %}
```

or

```
{{ func() }} 

to 

{% print func() %}
```

**but does not change if it contains a variable like:**

```
{{ var }} or {{ var.attr }}
```

I tried this:

```
pattern = re.compile( r'{{(?=(?:(?!{{)(?!\w([.]\w)*).*([()][+-/*%]\w)*)*}})')

temp_str = pattern.sub('{% print ', "{{ a }} {{ func() }} {{var.func()}} {{ a+ab+b*+2/100 }} {{ var.atr }} ")
```

It outputs:

```
'{% print  a }} {% print  func() }} {{ var.func()}} {% print a+ab+b*+2/100 }} {% print  var.atr }}'
```

Note: on closing braces `} I have to work.

The Output I expect is:

```
'{{  a }} {% print  func() }} {% print var.func()}} {% print a+ab+b*+2/100 }} {{ var.atr }}'
```

Comment: What characters are allowed in "expression"? Depending on whether you need to handle (escaped) brackets inside of the expression, regular expressions may not be the best way to handle this.

Comment: @mooiamaduck I made edit for what I tried.

Comment: You tried `temp_str = pattern.sub('{% print ', "{{ a }} {{ func() }} {{var.func()}} {{ a+ab+b*+2/100 }} {{ var.atr }} ")` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function in the `re.sub` method to catch all of the `{{<something>}}` tag, and then process each tag separately:

```
import re
data = "{{ a }} {{ func() }} {{var.func()}} {{ a+ab+b*+2/100 }} {{ var.atr}} "

def substitute(val):
    content = val.group(1)
    if re.match('^[\w\.]+$', content):
        return "{{ %s }}" % content
    else:
        return "{%% print %s %%}" % content
    pass

print re.sub("{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}", substitute, data)
```

Comment: This will outputs : {% print a %} {% print func() %} {% print var.func() %} {% print a+ab+b*+2/100 %} {% print var.atr %}  but I don't want to change {{ var }} or {{ a }} or {{ var.atr }} . Thanks @Mariusz Jamro

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Jamro

Comment: what will be the regex if I just want to convert {{}} into {% print %} only when there is a function() inside. Not convert it even when there is a string inside {{  }} which has function. For Example We only want to convert {{ fucntion() }} or {{ object.function() }} to {% print function()%} or {%print object.function()%} do not convert {{ "string" }}, arithmetic operations like {{ a+b }} or {{ "a+b" }} or {{ "functions() in string" }} or {{ var|filters }}

Comment: Please give me some help over my last comment

Comment: Ask a new question, it will be easier for someone to answer your queston

Comment: New Question  [regex-to-exclude-string-and-attribute-within-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884885/regex-to-exclude-string-and-attribute-within-expression)